# Updating select2 via angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui, angularjs-select2

I'm attempting to use Angular's $http directive to pull a list of tags from a server, and use that to populate a select2 select. My code looks like this:

```
    var samplePage = angular.module('samplePage', ['ui.select2']);

    samplePage.controller('sampleController', function($scope, $http) {
        console.log($scope);
        // THIS WORKS
        $scope.tags = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        $http.get('angular.html').success(function(rc) {
            console.log($scope);
            // THIS DOES NOT WORK
            $scope.tags = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
        })
    });

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['samplePage']);
```

However, the "tags" is not being updated! Or, rather, "tags" is being updated but the select2 widget does not seem to be binding properly.

The view looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="samplePage">
    <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <input id="tags" ui-select2="{tags:tags, simple_tags: true}" multiple ng-model="myTags" style="width: 150px;">
    <p>$scope.tags = {{tags}}<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a gist with a full test application: https://gist.github.com/poundifdef/6544542

Am I using the select2 module improperly? Or is there a bug in the module itself?

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-model` directive should be the `$scope` that will populate the select input. Use `ng-model="tags"`instead.

**EDIT**
When you have

```
<input id="tags" ui-select2="{tags:tags, simple_tags: true}" multiple ng-model="myTags" style="width: 150px;">
```

The `tags`in `ui-select2="{tags:tags, simple_tags: true}"`refers to the model you want to appear as options in the dropdown while `myTags` in `ng-model="myTags"` refers to the options that are selected.

If you want the list to be loaded with some options selected, set them in the controller as `$scope.myTags`. This should normally be a sub-set of the options (that is, `$scope.tags` here).

Comment: This is helpful! But not quite: when I change the code to say `ng-model="tags"`, the dropdown's options are still `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Theoretically, that list should no longer exist anywhere, if binding was done properly. Similarly, `['d', 'e', 'f']` never appear as options (even if I de-select them.)

Comment: @poundifdef you are performing a get request on the current page. Replace it with the source you want to load from and it will go away i.e. the a,b,c.